# Expected a "{" but found a "<". Block statements must be enclosed in "{" and "}"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I received the above error while trying to use the Html.EditorForModel helper in a view (MVC application). Here is the code  of the view:

```
@model CodeFirst.Models.Person

@{
   ViewBag.Title = "CreatePerson";
 }

<h2>CreatePerson</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
  <fieldset>
      <legend>Create person entry</legend>
      @Html.EditorForModel()
  </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

I was trying to use an editor template for Object type. Here is the template

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage
@if (Model == null)
    <span>@ViewData.ModelMetadata.NullDisplayText</span>
else
{
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="editor-table">
      @foreach (var prop in ViewData
     .ModelMetadata
     .Properties
     .Where(pm => pm.ShowForDisplay && !ViewData.TemplateInfo.Visited(pm)))
      {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @prop.GetDisplayName()
                </div>
            </td>
            <td width="10px">@(prop.IsRequired ? "*" : "") </td>
            <td>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    <span>@Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName)</span>
                    <span>@Html.ValidationMessage(prop.PropertyName, "*")</span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
  </table>
}
```

I found this sample in a MVC book. It adds an "*" character for required fields.
I receive the mentioned error when trying to access the view. If you have any idea why this error shows up, please let me know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like this the `if` statement is missing curly braces i.e.

```
@if (Model == null)
    <span>@ViewData.ModelMetadata.NullDisplayText</span>
else
```

Replace it with

```
@if (Model == null) {
    <span>@ViewData.ModelMetadata.NullDisplayText</span>
} else {
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks, that seems to have fixed the error; but now, it looks like I have a problem with my model or something, because all I can see in the "Create " view is this: {}; Only a pair of curly brackets shows; I'm using the code first approach. This is my model:    public class Person
    {
        [Key]
        public int PersonID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public Gender Sex { get; set; }
    }

Comment: That's a view specific problem, you can break into the code in the view with the debugger and see what HTML it's supposed to be returning.